# Emacs25 consumes more than 90% of three CPUs when no Emacs window is open

Tags: emacs, emacs25

I had three Emacs windows open. It was using more than 90% of three cores. Hence I closed all of them (C-x C).

Still the CPU usage (found using `top` command is the same.

Also I am not able to kill the Emacs25 process (using `k` while `top` is active)

What have I tried?
Read [this](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/9409). Didn't understand their solution.

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: sounds like you are running into an infinite loop, what is the value of `savehist-save-hook`?  This sounds like a spacemacs specific issue.  BTW you can kill the emacs zombie procs with `kill -9` if `pkill emacs` or `killall emacs` aren't working with SIGHUP

Comment: The solution in that link appears to be telling you to paste those 4 lines of code into the file `~/.emacs`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi M-x savehist-save-hook gives me multiple options asking me to "Click on a completion to select it"

Comment: its a variable not a function, type `C-h v` and enter its name or evaluate it with `M-:`